# Hiding information when fitting model in asreml-R

Tags: r, asreml

I'm using `asreml-R` package for my analysis. Whenever I stored a fitted model object `asreml-R` gives some extra information which I want to hide. See the code and the information below:

```
library(asreml)
dat <- data.frame(y=rnorm(20),x=seq(1,20))
ex.asr <- asreml(y ~ x, data=dat)

asreml(): 3.0.1 Library: 3.01gl IA32  Run: Wed May 30 13:26:44 2012

     LogLik         S2      DF
    -11.3850      0.7691    18  13:26:44
    -11.3850      0.7691    18  13:26:44

Finished on: Wed May 30 13:26:44 2012

LogLikelihood Converged
```

I would highly appreciate if you help to hide this extra information. Remember that  `asreml-R` is not an open source. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

use asreml's controlling stuff - the `asreml.control()` function control many aspects of asreml call, you can provide its arguments directly to asreml call, in you case you want to have `trace=F`, so e.g.

```
library(asreml)
dat <- data.frame(y=rnorm(20), x=seq(1,20))
ex.asr <- asreml(y ~ x, data=dat, trace=F)
```

Answer (score 2):

If (as it appears) that is something that is being `print()`'ed, you can use `capture.output()` to sink it to a temp file.

Here's an example:

```
plot(rnorm(99))

capture.output({
    lapply(1:4, function(X) abline(v=20*X))
}, file = tempfile())

## Here's the output that was sunk by `capture.output()`
## (wrapping the call in `suppressMessages()` won't get rid of those "NULL"s)
lapply(1:4, function(X) abline(v=20*x))
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

if `asreml-R` is well designed then putting `suppressMessages()` around the command should work. Otherwise I would suggest

```
sink("junk.txt")
## asreml command
sink()
```

Comment: Thank @Ben for your answer. `suppressMessages()` does not work with `asreml-R`. I will try your other suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Nice alternative. I like the bit of `?capture.output` that reads: "[‘capture.output is’] related to ‘sink’ in the same way that ‘with’ is related to ‘attach’.

Comment: Using `sink()` also gives the message in the output document.

Comment: The messages from asreml-r are sent to the screen by the Fortran code in the dll, so not directly controllable by R.  Use the 'asreml.control' function described below.